# Carrierwave_Direct with Jquery File Upload won't redirect due to cross-origin requests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, carrierwave, cors, jquery-file-upload

I am integrating Carrierwave_Direct and Jquery File Upload. Everything works fine. Files are uploaded to S3 directly without errors. However, the browser is not able to redirect users to the new url with key params such as

`http://example.com?bucket=your_fog_directory&key=uploads%2Fguid%2Ffile.ext&etag=%22d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427%22`.

on js console, the error message is

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://example.s3.amazonaws.com/. 
The request was redirected to 'http://example.com/users/settings?bucket=example&key=uploads…F1389525416-2-3762%2Fexample.jpg&etag=%225a44c7ba5bbe4ec867233d67e4806848%22', 
which is disallowed for cross-origin requests that require preflight.
```

I have already set up CORS on S3:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
    <CORSRule>
        <AllowedOrigin>http://example.herokuapp.com</AllowedOrigin>
        <AllowedOrigin>http://localhost:3000</AllowedOrigin>
        <AllowedMethod>PUT</AllowedMethod>
        <AllowedMethod>POST</AllowedMethod>
        <AllowedMethod>DELETE</AllowedMethod>
        <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
    </CORSRule>
    <CORSRule>
        <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
        <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
    </CORSRule>
```

JS codes:

```
$('#new_avatar_uploader').each(function(){
    var form = $(this),
        progress_bar = $('#new_avatar_uploader').find('.progress-bar');

    form.fileupload({
        progressall: function (e, data) {
                var progress = parseInt(data.loaded / data.total * 100, 10);
                progress_bar.css("visibility","visible");
                progress_bar.css(
                    'width',
                    progress + '%'
                );
            },
    });
});
```

Please help, thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Did you figure it out in the end?

Comment: in carrierwave / fog you can specify (force) a https call ":s3_protocol => :https"  and set your call to aws as https too and you should be fine. I always get this when i call http and render https (or the other way around)

Comment: Did you try setting 
<AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
on the post methods and see if works? I might be cause of the double allowedOrigin in the first rule.
Also, try to see why it's redirecting to example.com..since the rules don't mention that url anywhere

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can enable CORS for rails app:

Gemfile:

```
gem 'rack-cors'
```

config.ru (add at the bottom of the file):

```
# ...
require 'rack/cors'
use Rack::Cors do

  allow do
    origins 'http://example.herokuapp.com'
    resource '*',
             :headers => :any,
             :methods => [:put, :post, :delete, :options, :head],
             :max_age => 0,
             :expose => :location
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Ran into this problem as well and was unable to get the redirects to work, even after adding rack/cors and allowing everything. Instead, I ended up using action_status instead of the redirect. This returns an XML document with the necessary information (key) that you can then handle yourself.

Necessary changes are as follows.

In your Carrierwave config:

```
config.use_action_status = true
```

When setting up your uploader, change:

```
uploader.success_action_redirect = url
```

to

```
uploader.success_action_status = "201" # must be a string, or S3 throws errors
```

In your form, add:

```
= f.file_field :voter_file, :use_action_status => true
```

Then, in your Javascript (or, coffeescript):

```
form.fileupload
  dataType: 'xml'
  success: (retdata) ->
    # deal with the xml
```

Hope that helps.